# After Java7u45 java-web-start gives JARSigningException for some jars in my jnlp

Tags: swing, jar, java-web-start, jnlp, jar-signing

I am completely new in jarSigning issue but for a few days i am in trouble about this and searched/learned a lot. 
(This topic is not related to my problem: [Why does Java Web Start say a signed jar file is unsigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504705/why-does-java-web-start-say-a-signed-jar-file-is-unsigned) )

I use org.apache.commons packages in my java-web-start project and it worked with charm for years. Last week, after the java 7 update 45, our users were unable to run our application that runs via JNLP. The error they receive is "JARSigningException" related to some jars which belong to Apache. I removed the lines that correspond to these 6 jars from jnlp, then we were able to start the webstart application but in runtime we had some exceptions.

All jars are self-signed using same certificate (I myself have not signed them, but since we did not have a problem since a couple of days ago, they should have been signed with the same certificate)

When I verify a problematic jar file as below :
    jarsigner -verify commons-digester-1.7.jar

I receive below message :

```
jar verified.
```

Warning:

```
This jar contains unsigned entries which have not been integrity-checked.
This jar contains entries whose signer certificate has expired.
This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.

Re-run with the -verbose and -certs options for more details.
```

**If the Jar file is verified, why do i still receive the JARSigningException when I try to run the jnlp file?**

Any help would be appreciated, 
Thanks in advance,

Comment: I've solved my problem by downloading and signing jars. But i have still the main question: "what has changed?".. Same jars, same certificate. Was it about jarsigner version or "signing date" (not certificate expire date)?

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u45-relnotes-2016950.html for more information on the security changes in Java7 Update45.  The changes in U51 are starting to close the door on the security problems even more.    http://java.com/en/download/faq/release_changes.xml

The geneeral rule was that all jars within our downloaded JNLP application needed to be signed with the same certificate but like I said, I think there are tighter restrictions now about self-signed certificates.

Also found this blog https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/updated_security_baseline_7u45_impacts

The security slider setting (in Windows - control panel -> Java then Security tab) will prevent self-signed and unsigned applications when the setting is at High or Very High.